# Why the destructors are called twice for this functor?

Tags: c++, stl, foreach

When I run the following program, the destructor is called twice and I'm trying to understand why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class sample
{
    public:
        sample() { std::cout << "Constructor " << std::endl; }

        ~sample() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }

        void operator()(int i)
        {
            std::cout << i << " , "  << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> iNumbers;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        iNumbers.push_back(i);

    std::for_each(iNumbers.begin() , iNumbers.end() , sample() );
}
```

**The output is as folllows**

```
Constructor
0 ,
1 ,
2 ,
3 ,
4 ,
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic rule of three violation. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class sample
{
    public:
        sample() { std::cout << "Constructor " << std::endl; }

        sample(const sample&) { std::cout << "Constructor (copy)" << std::endl; }

        ~sample() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }

        sample& operator=(const sample&) { return *this; }

        void operator()(int i)
        {
                std::cout << i << " , "  << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> iNumbers;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
            iNumbers.push_back(i);

    std::for_each(iNumbers.begin() , iNumbers.end() , sample() );
}
```

Output is:

> Constructor
>   0 ,
>   1 ,
>   2 ,
>   3 ,
>   4 ,
>   Constructor (copy)
>   Destructor
>   Destructor

Comment: So this proves the copy in is elided in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But why does the copy constructor happen after all the elements are accessed and not before?

Comment: @user373215: The `for_each` function returns a copy of the function object you passed into it. Your class is not movable (or this is not C++11), so a copy has to be made.

Comment: Thanks David. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `std::for_each` takes its argument *by value*, and this results in a **copy** of the argument you provide being made.

Therefore, the destruction of the temporary you create by doing `sample()` will be responsible for one of those two destruction messages (the last one, since the temporary is destructed after the evaluation of the full expression that creates  it).

The first destruction message, on the other hand, comes from the destruction of the copy that `std::for_each` is working on.

Comment: Why does moving the object call the destructor 1 more time? (i.e `..., iNumbers.end() , std::move(sample()) )`

Comment: @0x499602D2: Probably because it prevents copy elision. It is possible that `std::for_each` is responsible internally for 2 of those messages, and the first one is not there because of copy elision (the temporary is constructed directly in the function argument).

Answer (score 2):

`std::for_each` will take the function object by value, causing it to be copied. So one destructor is called for the temporary object created by `sample()` and the other for the copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote a copy constructor, you would see that the functor is copied into the algorithm. Both copies are then destructed. There is a potential for the functor to be returned and there would be 3 copies, so one of the copies is being elided.